# PL SQL numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, plsql

On Executing this query, im having an error:

****Error report:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

ORA-06512: at line 34

06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"****
.

**My oracle version is:**
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production

please help me.. 
Regards,

```
 DECLARE CURSOR c1 is SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM All_Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%$%' AND Owner NOT IN ('WMSYS', 'EXFSYS', 'CTXSYS', 'WKSYS', 'SYSMAN', 'SYSTEM', 'FLOWS_030000', 'MDSYS', 'ORDSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'XDB', 'OLAPSYS');  
    col_names SYS_REFCURSOR; TYPE dat_res IS RECORD(tab_name VARCHAR2(1000),col_name VARCHAR2(1000)); 
    TYPE dr is table of dat_res; 
    act_dat dr:= dr(); 
    status NUMBER := 0; 
    cnt NUMBER := 1; 
    sql_stmt VARCHAR2(10000); 
    tab_name1 VARCHAR2(100); 
    col_name1 VARCHAR2(100); 

BEGIN 

FOR I IN C1 LOOP sql_stmt:= 'SELECT table_name,column_name FROM all_Tab_cols WHERE table_name = '||CHR(39)||I.table_name||CHR(39); 
OPEN col_names FOR sql_stmt; LOOP FETCH col_names INTO tab_name1,col_name1; 
EXIT WHEN col_names%NOTFOUND; 
BEGIN 


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
'SELECT 1 FROM '||tab_name1|| ' WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('||'TO_CHAR('||col_name1||'), '||CHR(39)||'^[%][a-bA-B]'||CHR(39)||') ' 
INTO status;


EXCEPTION 
WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN NULL;
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL; 
WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; 
END; 
IF (status = 1) THEN act_dat.extend; act_dat(cnt).tab_name:= tab_name1; act_dat(cnt).col_name:= col_name1; status := 0; cnt:= cnt + 1; 
END IF; END LOOP; 
CLOSE col_names; 
END LOOP; 
dbms_output.put_line('Table Name : Column Name'); 
FOR K IN act_dat.FIRST..act_dat.LAST LOOP insert into my_SAuditor_table VALUES (act_dat(K).tab_name, act_dat(K).col_name); 
END LOOP; 
Execute IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM my_SAuditor_table';
END;
```

Comment: Repost the pl/sql source code with line numbers

Comment: FOR K IN act_dat.FIRST..act_dat.LAST LOOP insert into my_SAuditor_table VALUES (act_dat(K).tab_name, act_dat(K).col_name);

THIS is the line #34

Comment: how is the my_sauditor table defined?

Comment: it is already been created. by

Comment: CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_SAuditor_table (TableName VARCHAR2(500), ColumnName VARCHAR2(500)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

Comment: what is the maximum length of the returned table and column names?

Comment: @steve, I think that in oracle the max length of a column or a table names is 30 characters

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might be looping over an empty collection.
You need to check that act_dr has some rows before using `act_dr.FIRST` and `act_dr.LAST`, otherwise you get null which is not a number.

This can be done with:

```
if act_dr.count > 0 then
FOR K IN act_dat.FIRST..act_dat.LAST LOOP 
   insert into my_SAuditor_table VALUES (act_dat(K).tab_name, act_dat(K).col_name); 
END LOOP;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that column table name definitions are not consistent. In the end you end up inserting a 1000 bytes column in a 512 bytes column and the funny part is, you only read the column with a max length of 100 bytes.

I'd advise to cleanup the code.

Comment: ahhh.. thanks steve.. Writing first oracle query in life, not getting your answer please elaborate it. thanking you..